# Simple but useful drawing softwares which fit for secondary student

Tags: geometry, math-software

My brother is now grade 6. I would like to look for some easy-to-use softwares, so that he can easily draw most basic shapes, some graphs by himself, without much instruction.

Comment: http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org) is easy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the best software for this is called "graph paper and pencil". And there's another useful tool called "eraser". Someone at secondary level should be building up their understanding through active learning. Producing a nice graph is not the purpose. The purpose is to build up one's own mental pictures through actively drawing curves and points. Even though I've been drawing graphs all my life, I still always draw them first on paper. Then I put them into the computer. And on the subject of "software", I recommend pencil softness 2B. A 2B pencil is easier to erase than HB.

Comment: Nice! I totally agree!